# R and Shiny: Using output of a reactive function

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

Currently I have a function [degtest] which is created in the shiny server, that returns a list,

```
return(list(datatable=datatable, predicttable=predicttable, esttable=esttable)
```

I want this list to be accessible after the function has run so that I can use different parts of the list to be rendered separately.

```
 outlist <- reactive({
   if(is.null(input$file2)){return(NULL)}
   if(input$d2 == 0){return(NULL)}
   with(data = reactdata$degdata, degtest(reactdata$degdata[,input$selectTemp], reactdata$degdata[,input$selectPot],reactdata$degdata[,input$selectWeight], reactdata$degdata[,input$selectTime], input$Temp0))
   })
```

input$file2 is my reactdata (reactdata$degdata and input$d2 is an action button.

I thought i'd be able to reference outlist$datatable but R says ' object of type 'closure' is not subsettable'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you are making an object `reactive`, you are actually making it into a sort of function (`closure`), so you have to use it as `outlist()` rather than `outlist`. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24745842/shiny-unable-to-see-dataframe-from-reactive-data-object/24745931#24745931) similar question. It's hard to answer your question considering you did not [provide a reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), but I think your solution will be something like `outlist()$ObjectYouAreTryingToAccess`.

Comment: Thank-you for this explanation, it worked and it's helped my understanding of it. Simply adding the () into where I was trying to reference it worked perfectly.

Thank-you for your help.